# How to configure Tomcat to use HTTP2 on Azure App Service?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, azure-web-app-service, spring-webflux, http2

I tried deploying a spring boot application as a war on an Azure App Service (Windows, java 8 , tomcat 8.5) .

It's a spring webflux application working with Server Sent Events so I *need* to have http2 support.

However even when http2 is enabled in the App Service I noticed that SSE is not working. 
Looking in the logs I find that it is still using HTTP/1.1 under the covers.

From kudu *D:\home\LogFiles\http\RawLogs*

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2019:20:19:43 +0000] "GET /api/rooms/someroom/users/Gms_2290/info/subscribe HTTP/1.1" 200 5 144
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2019:20:19:44 +0000] "GET /api/rooms/someroom/users/Gms_2290/music/subscribe HTTP/1.1" 200 5 16
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2019:20:19:46 +0000] "GET /api/rooms/someroom/users/Gms_2290/heartbeat HTTP/1.1" 200 5 142
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2019:20:19:46 +0000] "GET /api/rooms/someroom/users/Gms_2290/info/subscribe HTTP/1.1" 200 5 19
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2019:20:19:48 +0000] "GET /api/rooms/someroom/users/Gms_2290/music/subscribe HTTP/1.1" 200 5 32
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2019:20:19:49 +0000] "GET /api/rooms/someroom/users/Gms_2290/heartbeat HTTP/1.1" 200 5 16
```

**What I've tried**

- I tried playing with the java versions (switching between 8 and 9)
- I tried playing with the Tomcat versions (8.5 and 9)

**Linux angle**

I first tried deploying the application to a Linux App Service (with java 8 and Tomcat 8.5)

That resulted in following errors from the log Stream

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Async support must be enabled on a servlet and for all filters involved in async request processing
```

I suspect Tomcat might need some extra configuration in order to use the App Service SSL and thereby allowing http2, but I can't find a good way to configure the Tomcat used.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How do you know it's not working? Can you be more specific, what's the error message? From what I understand SSE are HTTP 1.1 stream requests and HTTP 2 is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I verified that a Spring WebFlux application that uses SSE works fine in App Service Linux when run as a jar file (using the Java SE 8 offering with HTTP 1.1). So the issue you are experiencing seems to be related to Tomcat configuration.

For investigation, can you share the repro that works fine on Tomcat locally but fails when run on Tomcat in App Service?